# disable multi-column selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is there any way to disable selection of multiple columns for a Swing JTable? I've disabled selection all together in the "Tid" column by overriding the selection intervals of the selection model:

```
myTable.getColumnModel().setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel() {
            private boolean isSelectable(int index0, int index1) {
                return index1 != 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
                if(isSelectable(index0, index1)) {
                    super.setSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
                if(isSelectable(index0, index1)) {
                    super.addSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
                }
            }
        });
```

And my guess is that one can also disallow the selection of multiple columns by overriding methods in the selection model. But I can't really figure out how to accomplish that.

**Allowed selection**
[image: Allowed Selection - the selection spans only one column but multiple rows]

**Disallowed selection**
[image: Disallowed Selection - the selection spans multiple columns and multiple rows]

Comment: please to see JTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);

Comment: @mKorbel Regarding your "extended" comment, I didn't say to use `JTable#setSelectionMode`, I said to get the `TableColumnModel` and use it's `ListSelectionModel`.  If you want to modify the behavior further, you will need to provide your own `ListSelectionModel` for it

Comment: @MadProgrammer then you missing hint for OP (column by overriding the selection intervals of the selection model) answer without getAnchor/LeadSelectionIndex

Comment: @mKorbel Yeah, I'm dumb, but if the OP just wants to limit the column selection to a single column, why do they need to do anything else?  Sure, they want to restrict selection so the first column can't be selected, which would suggest a custom `ListSelectionModel`

Answer (score 5):

First get the `TableColumnModel` from the `JTable`

```
TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
```

Next, get the `LstSeletionModel` for the `TableColumnModel`

```
ListSelectionModel selectionModel = columnModel.getSelectionModel();
```

With this, you could set the `selectionMode` that the model will use, for example

```
selectionModel.setSelectionModel(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION)
```

See the JavaDocs for [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) and [TableColumnModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html) for more details

## Runnable example....

[image: TableSelection]

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Test();
        }

        public Test() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        public class TestPane extends JPanel {

            public TestPane() {
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 10);
                for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
                    String[] data = new String[10];
                    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                        data[col] = row + "x" + col;
                    }
                    model.addRow(data);
                }


                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
                table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
                table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                add(new JScrollPane(table));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: From the JavaDocs for ListSelectionModel under SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION: "/../unless the given interval is immediately adjacent to or overlaps the existing selection, and can therefore be used to grow it". That is not what I am asking for - I don't want the user to be able to grow the selection (span) over multiple columns. I want them to be allowed to select multiple rows in the same column, but not multiple columns.

Comment: So, while you were reading the JavaDocs, you didn't notice `SINGLE_SELECTION`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was a simple enough addition to my already existing overrides that was needed.

```
@Override
public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
    if (isSelectable(index0, index1)) {
        if (index0==index1) { //The if condition needed.
            super.setSelectionInterval(index0, index1);             
        }
    }
}
```

I realised upon reviewing the JavaDoc and the `DefaultListSelectionModel` that the `index0` and `index1` were just what I was looking for - the column span. So by doing the call to the superclass if and only if the two column indices are equal, selection of multiple columns is not possible.